# Angular nf if else handling

Tags: angular

i have two user reports i.e. report abc & report xyz and for both i am using single html page with like if i need abc user reports then it shows a label and dropdown for abc and same for xyz but at a time which depends upon the report type here is the things i did for abc :-

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <span>{{reportType}}</span>
      <select [(ngModel)]="selectedabcuser">
        <option *ngFor="let user of abcUsers" [value]="user.id">
          {{user.name}} ({{user.id}})
        </option>
      </select>
</div>
```

but issue is am unable to handle it for xyz users. Any leads please.

Comment: share more detail. Do you have 2 variables abcUsers and xyzUsers? Do you want to display only 1 dropdown for both the users depending upon a condition?

Comment: thanks komal ! for follwing up. Below is the hierarchy of reports            Reports
  ---abcuserreport
  ---xyzuserreport

if i click on abc userreports it redirects html page having abcuser with user details dropdown
and 
if i click on xyzuserreport then it should redirects html page having xyzuser with user details in dropdown

for getting data am using service.ts which fetching data via API

Comment: What is your code in component? You need to use a common variable like allUSers and assign xyzUsers /abcUsers to allUsers based on page it is rendering. More clarity will come after having component code.

Answer (score 0):

Anyhow you need two select dropdowns on the report,

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <span>{{reportType}}</span>
      <ng-container *ngIf="reportType ==='abc'">
      <select [(ngModel)]="selectedabcuser">
        <option *ngFor="let user of abcUsers" [value]="user.id">
          {{user.name}} ({{user.id}})
        </option>
      </select>
      </ng-container>
     <ng-container *ngIf="reportType ==='xyz'">
      <select [(ngModel)]="selectedxyzuser">
        <option *ngFor="let user of xyzusers" [value]="user.id">
          {{user.name}} ({{user.id}})
        </option>
      </select>
     </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks sajeethran .... i need two dropdown field but one a time and that should be matching to report type criteria        the report hierarchy is below :-                                                                                                                 
 Reports
  ---abcuserreport
  ---xyzuserreport

if i click on abc userreports it redirects html page having abcuser with user details dropdown
and 
if i click on xyzuserreport then it should redirects html page having xyzuser with user details in dropdown

for getting data am using service.ts which fetching data via API

Comment: you need to pass the selected value and use router.navigate. mark if the answer helped

Answer (score 0):

You have to get your variables dynamically, e.g. by calling a function:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <select [(ngModel)]="selectedUser">
        <option *ngFor="let user of getUserMap('abc').data" [value]="user.id">
          {{user.name}} ({{user.id}})
        </option>
      </select>
</div>
```

Typescript:

```
type UserType = 'abc' | 'xyz';

interface User {
    name: string;
    id: string;
}

interface UserMap {
     type: UserType;
     data: User[];
}

export class YourComponent {

    public selectedUser: User;

    public users: UserMap[] = [ 
        { type: 'abc', data: [{ name: 'foo', id: '1' }] }, 
        { type: 'xzy', data : [{ name: 'bar', id: '2' }] }, 

    ];

    public getUserMap(type: UserType): UserMap {
        // returns this.users[0] if called with getUsers('abc')
        this.users.find(userMap => userMap.type === type)
    }

 }
```